# xls table fail responsive to mobile view at opencart 3.0.3.8

Tags: javascript, php, css, json, xls

I have upload an exel table to OpenCart 3.0.3.8 of product description content and it is not responsive to mobile view. So I go to setting/custom codes/custom CSS/add the below CSS code:

```
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
} 

#description. content {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

But the table still not responsive to mobile, what can I do? Anyone can help?

my table only can see part of the size table at mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/An8VR.png)

I want to have all size table can be showed at mobile
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRRuj.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text directly in the question, not as a link to an image.

Comment: element.style {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
} 

#description .content {
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

Comment: Add all the relevant code from the image to your question by editing it.

Comment: When I post the code, the message is appeared ---Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: This is normal. All you have to do is to add *```* in a line before your code and in line after your code.

Comment: I recommend reading guidelines about [asking a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also about [editing and formatting your posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to attract more people that could help you in the future.